# Unrecognized name "rank" in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm writing a query to get the top ten of each area. The query return correctly the ranks, but when I try to get only the top ten, it return an unrecognized name error, even though I declare its name.

```
with rank as (
select RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY area ORDER BY total_orders_last30days DESC) 
FROM `dataset`)
SELECT orders, name, area,  
FROM `dataset` where rank<=10
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems with your code:

- You define a CTE but don't use it.
- You have a column in the CTE but don't provide an alias.
- You refer to the original dataset, which doesn't have that column.

This is what you want:

```
WITH r as (
      SELECT d.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY area ORDER BY total_orders_last30days DESC) as rnk
      FROM `dataset` d
    )
SELECT orders, name, area,  
FROM r
wHERE rnk <= 10 ;
```

Comment: @AaronG . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: This returns several repeated records in different ranks, the same name can't be top 1 and top 3. Sorry I clicked accepted, just realized this when ordered the table by area

Comment: @AaronG. . .  Then answers the question that  YOU asked.  If you don't want "repeated" records like that, then use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  `RANK()` is not guaranteed to remove 10 records.  This question is answered.  You should actually be asking a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: How can the same record have different ranks? It can't posible be first in a race and at the same time 6th

Comment: @AaronG. . . . I'm going to repeat.  This answers the question you asked here.  You seem to have other questions.  Ask a new question with sample data, desired results and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.